# Quando crio um Form deforma o Button

Tags: javascript, formulário

Quando eu crio um Form usando JS para abrir ao click de um Button, o texto o Button é deformado.

```css
#openSendForm{
    background: #0ebd64;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    right: 70px;
    top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Futura";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="StyleMain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Teste</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            
        $(function() {
            dialog = $("#teste1").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 500,
                width: 500,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                  Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog( "close" );
                  }
                }
            });
          
            $("#openSendForm").button().on( "click", function() 
            {
                dialog.dialog( "open" );
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="openSendForm" value="Enviar Torrent">
        
        <div id="teste1">
            <input type="file" id="teste" value="Escolher Torrent">
            <input type="button" id="teste2" value="Enviar">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Quando eu não estou usando o botão para abrir o Form ele fica dessa forma(`$("")`): [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem quando eu uso ele para abrir o Form fica desta forma(`$("#openSendForm")`):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não  compreendi exatamente a sua dúvida

Comment: Teu código ta funcionando normal, não entendi o erro também. EDIT: Você quer dizer que o estilo dos botões dentro do popup estão diferentes dos botões de fora?

Comment: @LocalHost  Mude `$("#openSendForm")` para `$("")` e perceba a diferença no botão.

Comment: Percebi, mas ainda continuo sem entender o que quer realmente

Comment: @LocalHost Quero que o botão não fique bugado, eu não sei por que o texto vai pra baixo e ele perde as bordas, gostaria que ele continuasse normal. Entende ??

Comment: @LocalHost Olá, eu editei a pergunta, após ver seu código lembrei que me esqueci de colocar o CSS junto a pergunta.

Comment: Como você queria que ficasse? Voce esta falando falando que o texto do botão esta muito para baixo?

Comment: @LocalHost Coloquei na pergunta a diferença.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você estava definindo valor fixo para o tamanho: Use o `padding` que é uma margem para dentro, assim garante que fica de maneira igualitária o tamanho

```css
#openSendForm{
    background: #0ebd64;
    position: absolute;
  
padding: 10px 30px;
    right: 70px;
    top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Futura";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="StyleMain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Teste</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            
        $(function() {
            dialog = $("#teste1").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 500,
                width: 500,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                  Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog( "close" );
                  }
                }
            });
          
            $("#openSendForm").button().on( "click", function() 
            {
                dialog.dialog( "open" );
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="openSendForm" value="Enviar Torrent">
        
        <div id="teste1">
            <input type="file" id="teste" value="Escolher Torrent">
            <input type="button" id="teste2" value="Enviar">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sim, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="StyleMain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <title>Teste</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
   
  $(function() {
   dialog = $("#teste1").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
     $(this).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
   });
    
   $("#openSendForm").button().on( "click", function() 
   {
    dialog.dialog( "open" );
   });
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="button" id="openSendForm" value="Enviar Torrent">
  
  <div id="teste1" title="Escolha o Torrent">
  
   <input type="file" id="teste" value="Escolher Torrent"  class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget"><br><br>
   <input type="button" id="teste2" value="Enviar"  class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget"> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Para customizar botão input file, siga esse  link:
https://jsfiddle.net/xnVHr/70/

Comment: Olá, eu editei a pergunta, após ver seu código lembrei que me esqueci de colocar o CSS junto a pergunta.